# How to change address book drop(Billing) down to pre-populated form?

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, billing-address

If `$this->customerHasAddresses('billing')` this method is set to true or if customer has their addresses registered, magento will show the existing address as the drop down options. how to show those values as pre populated form instead of dropdown option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy this `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php` to  `app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php`

check the function `getAddressesHtmlSelect` on line `110`.

do you changes in that function as you required.